# Deleting column of huge fits file

Tags: python-3.x, astropy, memory-mapping, fits

I am having a relatively large dataset (~30GB) in fits format which does not fit into memory. In some instance I need to add one column and later on remove it from that file.

Adding the column seems to work with help of the `fitsio.insert_column` method, however I have not come across a similar method in various packages that removes that column again without having to read in the whole data. Am I missing an obvious function or is it something about the fits format that does not allow to do this in a simple and memory efficient fashion?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I know this is probably not the most useful answer, but FITS is not well suited for manipulation of large columnar data sets.  You might do better to convert to an HDF5, do your manipulations with HDF5 libraries, and if you *must* produce a FITS file you can re-serialize to FITS when you're done working with the data.

Comment: I should add, `astropy.Table` includes optional support for reading/writing files from/to HDF5: http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/unified.html#hdf5